# Objective-C: Declaring a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, properties

If I want to declare a simple button, do I have to do *both* of the following things?

Inside @interface:

`UIButton *button;`

and

`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;`

Is the property declaration sufficient, or are both needed? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part, in the @interface, is an ivar declaration. You no longer need to do this if you're declaring a property. In fact, it's a good idea to stop doing this, because it's a private implementation detail that you're exposing in your header.

The second part is a property declaration. This is all you really need. However, if you declare the property, you also need to synthesize the accessors. In your .m file, at the top of your `@implementation` block, just stick

```
@synthesize button;
```

The `@synthesize` tells the property what ivar to use for its backing store. And on modern runtimes (which is iOS and 64-bit OS X) it will also synthesize the ivar for you. So I guess if you're writing 32-bit OS X code, you still need the ivar declaration, but that's the only time.

Answer (score 0):

Apple guys has removed such redundancy by adding a feature (non-fragile abi blablabla) to clang. You can write @property and @synthesize, without ivars inside @interface ClassName{}.

Comment: I think you're referring to automatic @synthesizing of properties. We've had non-fragile ivars for a while now.

Comment: To be fair, 32-bit OS X programs still have the non-fragile ivar issue, but iOS and 64-bit OS X don't, and that's where most development is these days.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. If I have a 3rd-party base class not using such feature, can I subclass it with such automatic synthesized properties?

Comment: You can synthesize ivars as long as you're targeting either iOS or 64-bit OS X. The only time you *can't* is if you're targeting 32-bit OS X.